# WPF, How to Animate ListViewItems

Tags: wpf, listview, animation

I'm developing a touchscreen application, have a listview with a DataTemplate which has a single mediaelement in it. I can drag,move scale each individual listview item, now I need a code to bring all of the listview items to their first positions with scaling back to first size and moving to first position. How can I do this, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure that all of the panning, zooming and rotating are just RenderTransforms, and then just animate the RenderTransforms back to Zero. (or 1 in the case of ScaleTransform)
this way they will return to their original place.

For example, if you have ScaleTransform called st then you can reset it to it's original settings like so

```
DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
da.To = 1
da.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.2);

st.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleX, da);
```

since I only put in the `To` value and not the `From` value - it would go back no matter what its current value is.

Comment: Elad, could you post a sample code for animating RenderTransforms back to zero? Thanks